# Changing the background of list items by click on a separate button

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView with some items now I want to change the background color or item text color by click on a separate button which IS NOT on the list . How can I do that in my android app?

This is my main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    arrayAdapter = new SubArrayAdapter(this, dataItemList);
    ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    ImageButton btn_check = findViewById(R.id.button_checkout);
    btn_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

// how can I access the list items within this click-handler method

});
```

List Item Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listitems"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/yes_image"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/no_image"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/paragraph_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/yes_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/yes_image"
    android:textColor="@color/paragraph_items_colro"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_main xml layout file:

```
android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textDirection="ltr"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="#0f0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mylist">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_checkout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/checkout_9"
        android:src="@drawable/checkout_9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mylist"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="106dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I have myown adapter class that in the getview() method I populated the list items

this inner class is located in mainactivity:

```
   private class SubArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataItem> {
    private List<DataItem> items;
    private Context context;

    public SubArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<DataItem> 
        items) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitems, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
       ViewGroup parent) {
        DataItem dataitem1 = items.get(position);
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
       context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitems, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.paragraph_description);
        tv.setText(dataitem1.getDescription());
        tv.setTag(position + 100);
        ImageView yes_iv = view.findViewById(R.id.yes_image);
        int yes_res = context.getResources().getIdentifier("yes", 
                                             "drawable", getPackageName());
        yes_iv.setImageResource(yes_res);
        yes_iv.setTag(position + 200);
        //yes_iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ImageView no_iv = view.findViewById(R.id.no_image);
        int no_res = context.getResources().getIdentifier("no", "drawable", 
        getPackageName());
        no_iv.setImageResource(no_res);
        no_iv.setTag(position + 300);
        return view;
    }
  }

    }
```

Comment: `How can I do that in android studio?` In Android Studio? In your Android app you mean.

Comment: Please provide more information like  - what did You do in Your project so far. You should proof You've made something and Your are not waiting for ready solution. Please look at others questions, they give few things: problem what they are dealing with, code what did they do so far, question about strict problem.

Comment: Could You show me the layout of item used on the list?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed You have set `android:listSelector` for `ListView` in Your `activity_main.xml` - which was giving You an ability to change item's background on single click.

So I decided to check out how it works in `ListView` class.

I've looked at source code of `ListView` and searched for phrase `selector`. There was the line:

```
} else if (mAction == STATE_REQUEST_FOCUS) {
        final int childIndex = mPosition - mFirstPosition;
        final View child = getChildAt(childIndex);
        if (child != null) {
            child.requestFocus();
        }
        mAction = -1;
    }
```

---

```
final View child = getChildAt(childIndex);
```

---

Following these steps - I knew solution for Your question problem. Here it is:

```
ImageButton imageButton = findViewById(R.id.button_checkout);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int hardCodedPoositionToSelect = 1;

        View childAt = listView.getChildAt(hardCodedPoositionToSelect);
        if (childAt != null) {
            //change background
            childAt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            //change textView color of current view
            TextView paragraphDescription = childAt.findViewById(R.id.paragraph_description);
            paragraphDescription.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        }
    }
});
```

You can see I am calling `getChildAt()` on `listView` to obtain current item's view basing on item's position from `hardCodedPoositionToSelect`.